# Looping the date of a week until a holiday is found within that week

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a requirement where in a timesheet I need to disable the fields when a holiday falls on a week I need to make that day's fields to be disabled. But its looping till the end of the holidays present in the database. for example, I am taking startdate as 11.08.2013 and I need to loop till 15.08.2013 for this week as 15th Aug is India's Independence Day.

On 15th Aug the field should be disabled. But here I am getting the value like Christmas which is the last Public Holiday of the year and its getting affected for all the days...

Code:

```
DateTime dtstart = Convert.ToDateTime(startdate);
con.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("select * from ind_holidays", con);
OleDbDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
while (dr1.Read())
{
    string holiday = dr1[0].ToString();
    string date = dr1[1].ToString().Substring(0, 10);
    DateTime holi_date = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
    while (dtstart <= holi_date)
    {
        if (dtstart.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
        { 
                devmontxt.Text = holiday;
                devmontxt.Enabled = false;
                trmontxt.Text =  holiday;
                trmontxt.Enabled = false;
                lunmontxt.Text = holiday;
                lunmontxt.Enabled = false;
                permontxt.Text = holiday;
                permontxt.Enabled = false;
                totmontxt.Text = holiday;
                totmontxt.Enabled = false;

        }
        if (dtstart.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
        { 

                devtuetxt.Text = holiday;
                devtuetxt.Enabled = false;
                trtuetxt.Text =  holiday;
                trtuetxt.Enabled = false;
                luntuetxt.Text =  holiday;
                luntuetxt.Enabled = false;
                pertuetxt.Text =  holiday;
                pertuetxt.Enabled = false;
                tottuetxt.Text = holiday;
                tottuetxt.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (dtstart.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
        { 

                devwedtxt.Text =  holiday;
                devwedtxt.Enabled = false;
                trwedtxt.Text = holiday;
                trwedtxt.Enabled = false;
                lunwedtxt.Text =  holiday;
                lunwedtxt.Enabled = false;
                perwedtxt.Text =  holiday;
                perwedtxt.Enabled = false;
                totwedtxt.Text =  holiday;
                totwedtxt.Enabled = false;   
        }
        if (dtstart.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
        {
            devthutxt.Text = holiday;
            devthutxt.Enabled = false;
            trthutxt.Text = holiday;
            trthutxt.Enabled = false;
            lunthutxt.Text = holiday;
            lunthutxt.Enabled = false;
            perthutxt.Text = holiday;
            perthutxt.Enabled = false;
            totthutxt.Text = holiday;
            totthutxt.Enabled = false;

        }

        if (dtstart.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
        {
            devfritxt.Text = holiday;
            devfritxt.Enabled = false;
            trfritxt.Text = holiday;
            trfritxt.Enabled = false;
            lunfritxt.Text = holiday;
            lunfritxt.Enabled = false;
            perfritxt.Text = holiday;
            perfritxt.Enabled = false;
            totfritxt.Text = holiday;
            totfritxt.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (dtstart.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        {
                devsattxt.Text =  holiday;
                devsattxt.Enabled = false;
                trsattxt.Text =  holiday;
                trsattxt.Enabled = false;
                lunsattxt.Text =  holiday;
                lunsattxt.Enabled = false;
                persattxt.Text = holiday;
                persattxt.Enabled = false;
                totsattxt.Text =  holiday;
                totsattxt.Enabled = false;    

        }
        dtstart = dtstart.AddDays(1);
        continue;
    }
}
dr1.Close();
con.Close();
```

}

Comment: Why don't you modify your query to only return holidays that fall within a specified range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to find the last day of the week.

```
lastDay = dtstart.AddDays(7);
```

Now, since you have both the start and end day, you can query only the holidays in that week.

```
select * from ind_holidays where holiday_day between @dtstart and @lastDay order by holiday_day
```

The first element returned by the query will be the first holiday of the week.

An other option would be to fetch all holidays and store them in a list. Then you just need to loop the items in the list.

Comment: FYI I'm storing only the name of the holiday and date of the holiday in the that table

Answer (score 0):

keep your holidays in list and loop for only a week from present day and check if list contains any value in your loop disable it .
Use current datetime and add number of days you want .